# Autoplay stops after 1 fade when using fade effect in swiper js

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I have a slider that I want to set to autoplay and have a fade effect. Everything works fine when using the normal slide effect but after I added the fade it stops working after 1 fade. It's also not fading but just instantly changing to the next slide, only when I manually use my mouse to slide it shows a fade effect.

What could be the issue?

In my js file I import the 'EffectFade' like this:

```
import Swiper, {Autoplay, Navigation, Pagination, EffectFade} from 'swiper';
Swiper.use([Autoplay, Navigation, Pagination, EffectFade]);
```

Then my swiper code:

```
new Swiper('#agrarisch .swiper-container', {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    // spaceBetween: 30,
    effect: 'fade',
    autoplay: {
        delay: 2500,
    },
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '#agrarisch .swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '#agrarisch .swiper-button-prev',
    }
});
```

[Example video](https://streamable.com/kdymsv)

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure this one out? I'm having the same issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by including the fade effect CSS:

```
// Node
@import "./node_modules/swiper/swiper";
@import "./node_modules/swiper/modules/effect-fade/effect-fade";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This answer is useful for me. In my project, I am using Less styles and the following code solves the issue: `@import "~swiper/less";
@import "~swiper/less/effect-fade";`

This official link should be useful to you: https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#css-styles

Answer (score 1):

The same problem arose for me.
In my case, I solved it by loading "swiper-bundle.min.css" instead of "swiper.min.css".

Answer (score 1):

Anyone struggling with autoplay effect fade in swiper slider must try this example:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".home-slider", {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    effect: "fade",
    centeredSlides: true,
    fadeEffect: { crossFade: true },
    autoplay: {
      delay: 7500,
      disableOnInteraction: true,
    },
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true,
    },
       navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
      },
});
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76335803/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).